# how can I read dynamic value in ui in e2e protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, dynamic, protractor

I'm developing e2e test in protractor. I'm running the test chrome browser.
In UI there is a dynamic field :

```
<div ng-show="searchResult.count" >
            <h4>Search Results: </h4>
            <p id="font-weight-500">{{searchResult.count}} Items</p>
            <hr>
      </div>
```

I need to take the value of **searchResult.count**

I tried

```
element(by.binding('searchResult.count'));

$('[ng-show="searchResult.count"]')
```

;

I did some change in html and added ng-model='shearchResult.count' in div

```
<div ng-show="searchResult.count"  ng-model="searchResult.count">
```

then I call

```
element(by.model("searchResult.count"));
```

All of them's result is same:

```
 <h4>Search Results: </h4>
 <p id="font-weight-500" class="ng-binding"> Items</p>
 <hr>
```

I also tried to use $scope

```
SearchPage.prototype.getSearchResultNumber=function($scope){
....        
    var value=$scope.searchResult.count;
....
```

But I've got the "$scope" is undefined result
Although I can see the number in web browser I cannot read or take in e2e spec in protractor.

How can I get this dynamically generated data?
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround it by using [`getAttribute()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute) to get the value of `ng-model` attribute:

```
var div = element(by.model("searchResult.count"));
expect(div.getAttribute('ng-model')).toBe('10');  // 10 is an example
```

Comment: div = element(by.model("searchResult.count")); returns empty string I cannot read "SearchResult.count" . My problem is this –  user1024855 36 secs ago    edit

Comment: @user1024855 have you solved that last problem you had?